# After succesfull Ajax call show div and replace span with new span

Tags: php, jquery, fadein

I have a form I submit through ajax:

```
 $(function() {
 $(".submit").click(function() {
var listid = $("#listid").val();
var itemid = "<?=$id?>";
var userid = "<?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>"; 

 var dataString = 'listid=' + listid + '&userid=' + userid + '&itemid=' + itemid;


 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "join.php",
 data: dataString,
 success: function(){
 $('#content_error').fadeIn(200).show();
 }
 });

 return false;
 });
 });
```

This works perfectly. The ajax function calls join.php:

```
  <? session_start();

require_once("include/database.php");
$Db = new Database();

 if($_POST['listid'] && $_POST['itemid'] && $_POST['userid']) {

            $list_id = $_POST['listid'];
            $user_id = $_POST['userid'];
            $item_id = $_POST['itemid'];

            $sql = "SELECT *
                    FROM items_list
                    WHERE list_id = '".$list_id."'
                    AND user_id = '".$user_id."'
                    AND item_id = '".$item_id."'
                    ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 1";
            $result = $Db->sQuery($sql);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){

                $error = "You've already saved this";   

            }else{

            $sql = "INSERT INTO items_list (list_id, user_id, item_id) 
                    VALUES('$list_id', '$user_id', '$item_id')";
            $Db->uidQuery($sql);

            $sql = "SELECT count(item_id) as itemm
                    FROM items_list 
                    WHERE item_id = '".$item_id."'
                    GROUP BY item_id";          
            $result = $Db->sQuery($sql);
            $Db->closeConnection();
            $tel2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            ?>
                <span class="bubble_itemm"><?=$tel2['itemm']?></span>


            <?
                $success = "Sucessfully";

            }
        }
```

?>

After a success I call a span with the class bubble_itemm. This span also exists in the main page. I want the "new" span to replace the "old" span in the main page with a fadein.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
        var listid = $("#listid").val();
        var itemid = "<?=$id?>";
        var userid = "<?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>"; 

        var dataString = 'listid=' + listid + '&userid=' + userid + '&itemid=' + itemid;


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "join.php",
            data: dataString,
        }).done(function( result ) {
            myresult(result);
        });

        return false;
    });
});

function myresult(result) {
    var result_lines = result.split("<splitter>");    
    if (result_lines[0] == '1') { 
        $('.bubble_itemm').html('<span class="error">' + result_lines[1] + '</span>').fadeIn(500);
    } else if (result_lines[0] == '2') { 
        $('.bubble_itemm').html('<span class="success">' + result_lines[1] + '</span>').fadeIn(500);
    }
    return true;   
}

</script>
```

join.php script:

```
<?php 

require_once("include/database.php");
$Db = new Database();

if($_POST['listid'] && $_POST['itemid'] && $_POST['userid']) {

    $list_id = $_POST['listid'];
    $user_id = $_POST['userid'];
    $item_id = $_POST['itemid'];

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM items_list
            WHERE list_id = '".$list_id."'
            AND user_id = '".$user_id."'
            AND item_id = '".$item_id."'
            ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $Db->sQuery($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "1<splitter>"; // here to identify message status
        echo "You've already saved this"; // return message

    }else{

        $sql = "INSERT INTO items_list (list_id, user_id, item_id) 
                VALUES('$list_id', '$user_id', '$item_id')";
        $Db->uidQuery($sql);

        $sql = "SELECT count(item_id) as itemm
                FROM items_list 
                WHERE item_id = '".$item_id."'
                GROUP BY item_id";          
        $result = $Db->sQuery($sql);
        $Db->closeConnection();
        $tel2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        echo "2<splitter>"; // here to identify message status
        echo $tel2['itemm']; // return message
        echo "Sucessfully"; // return message

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Gustonez,

I want 2 things:

1. On a div I need to show the "error" or "success" message
2. On a span I need to update the count 

Your solution is not the way I guess...

Comment: Gustonez,

A small additional question: One of the lines after a splitter is echo json_encode($test);. I want to return this array to a javascript at the page the ajax call is made... how do I do this? I'm receiving this as html output: ["image.jpeg","image.jpg"]

Comment: you can simply return javascript code from the returned ajax response. example: `echo '<script>javascript_function();</script>';` this function will be fired as soon as ajax finish loading. so parse json_whatever from php then return it as javascript.

Comment: Oke that's clear... I will try that... I have on other question left... I have 2 lines in the script above echo $tel2['itemm']; and echo "Successfully";. Can I also output every line apart? Cause now they are combined

Comment: as you noticed `<splitter>` is the delimiter, put it at the end of each line you want to separate. back to the script - when you do this: `var result_lines = result.split("<splitter>");` this will explode it into array. `result_lines[0], result_lines[1], result_lines[2], etc..`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
 $(".submit").click(function() {
var listid = $("#listid").val();
var itemid = "<?=$id?>";
var userid = "<?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>"; 

 var dataString = 'listid=' + listid + '&userid=' + userid + '&itemid=' + itemid;


 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "join.php",
 data: dataString,
 success: function(data){
 $('#content_error').fadeIn(200).show();
 $('.bubble_itemm').text(data);
 }
 });

 return false;
 });
 });
```

$('.bubble_itemm').text(data); add this code and remove the span tag from join.php insted of that just echo the text that you want inside your span.

```
<? session_start();

require_once("include/database.php");
$Db = new Database();

 if($_POST['listid'] && $_POST['itemid'] && $_POST['userid']) {

            $list_id = $_POST['listid'];
            $user_id = $_POST['userid'];
            $item_id = $_POST['itemid'];

            $sql = "SELECT *
                    FROM items_list
                    WHERE list_id = '".$list_id."'
                    AND user_id = '".$user_id."'
                    AND item_id = '".$item_id."'
                    ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 1";
            $result = $Db->sQuery($sql);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){

                $error = "You've already saved this";   

            }else{

            $sql = "INSERT INTO items_list (list_id, user_id, item_id) 
                    VALUES('$list_id', '$user_id', '$item_id')";
            $Db->uidQuery($sql);

            $sql = "SELECT count(item_id) as itemm
                    FROM items_list 
                    WHERE item_id = '".$item_id."'
                    GROUP BY item_id";          
            $result = $Db->sQuery($sql);
            $Db->closeConnection();
            $tel2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            ?>
                <? echo $tel2['itemm'];?>


            <?
                $success = "Sucessfully";

            }
        }
```

and if you want fade in effect use this code

```
$('.bubble_itemm').fadeOut(1000,function(){ $(this).text(data).fadeIn(1000); });
```

Comment: i wonder if you did notice $success and $error variables; how did you let the user know if it succeeded or not?

Comment: @anooj,

this doesn't work for me. He doesn't set the count in the span

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly help if you assigned an id to the target span in the main page. Doing something to a class of spans will effect all spans of that class. Maybe that's desired.

You can add any number of functions to the success part of your AJAX request. The functions that you should investigate are [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), and [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).  These should be called in sequence using callbacks. For example

```
$('#old_span_id').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $(new_span).insertAfter('#where_want_it_to_go');
    $(new_span).fadeIn();
});
```

Something like that anyway, I'd need to see a bit more HTML to give you a more fuller answer.